# SVN error PUT OF

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.6. while I try to commit some folder, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):
Error: PUT of  
Error: '/svn/asc01/a277f5016a0d/Components/branches/02_GeneratedSource/Intern_Out.c'   
Error: SSL negotiation failed: SSL error: parse tlsext (https://asc-xxxx)
```

How to get rid of this?

Comment: a new added file or a modified file? Below may meet your issue: 1.Check if exists file with the same name.   2.Try to cleanup you workcopy and commit again.

Comment: @Cheers nope, it won't help.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN 1.6.6 is *very outdated*. Upgrade at least to 1.6.17.

(This is a client-side bug in OpenSSL library which was fixed in OpenSSL 0.9.8m).

"Troubleshooting 'SSL error: parse tlsext' error message": http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00046/